# What is Public ID in guidewire PC integration

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Why we use public ID in guidewire integration. Please explain I am new to guidewire. What is importance of Public ID with example.

Comment: You should read the docs instead

Answer (score 1):

Following the Guidewire documentation, the PublicID is:

> For Guidewire business entities, the PublicID property is the main key
> property that identifies the entity to an external system. Typically
> an external system needs the PublicID property, but only if there is a
> reason to export the object. For example, if important property
> changed on it or the object is new or added to an entity array. For an
> incremental export (only changed data), if an entity does not change
> and no subobject changes, Gosu does not export the object.

Answer (score 0):

PublicID is an unique identifier (like a Primary Key), in your integration may be the ID of that object in the remote system (PC, BC, CC, AB).